# Is it costly to create a .aspx page only to expose WebMethods for all other pages?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have read to use .ashx for AJAX functions and NOT .aspx since there is a lot of overhead with .aspx

However, webmethods like the one shown as an example here are Shared, which a .NET evangelist explained was necessary to circumvent overhead with the page.

So, what are the dangers of creating a GlobalWebMethods.aspx to be called from other pages in the application?

The reason I want to do this is because it accepts and returns JSON objects via POST without having to write any serialization/deserialization code, can accept JSON objects as a VB class, and also has access to the user Session.

If there is a way to do that with .ashx, I am unaware of it.

Example Code: GlobalWebmethodFunctions.aspx.vb

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
<ScriptMethod()> _
Public Shared Function ExampleFunc(ObjID As Integer) As MyNamespace.Message
    If HttpContext.Current.Session("CompanyID") Is Nothing Then
        Throw New Exception("LOGGED OUT")
    End If

    Dim db As New MyNamespace.Database()

    Dim UserID As Integer = HttpContext.Current.Session("UserID")

    Dim msg As New MyNamespace.Message

    msg.Message = "Success!"

    Return msg
End Function
```